# Why are there two .NET 4.0 Frameworks showing in IIS Application Pools?

Tags: .net, windows, iis

Why are there two versions of the .NET Framework 4.0 showing up in the Application Pool dialog in IIS?

The server is running Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0 and TFS 2012.

It seems strange that there is a **v4.0.30319** and a **.NET Framework v4.0.30319**.

[image: IIS Application Pool dialog]
[image: IIS Applications Pools]

Answer (score 1):

Is the server running TFS? If yes, then probably the 2nd pool was created during installation of TFS.